# Creating a circular mouseover saturation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, mouseover

I have two versions of an image: a desaturated version and a full color version. What I want to accomplish is a hover effect in which mousing over the desaturated image reveals a circle of the color version of the image. It would be sort of like shining a spotlight on the desaturated image to show its color. And then when you move the mouse away, it would fade back to its desaturated state.

I know I could probably use flash, but I'd like to do this with JavaScript and CSS. Ideally this would degrade to just an image if JavaScript is disabled and could be fluid in width (responsive).

Comment: Updated my answer with a demo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### border-radius

CSS3 `border-radius` can be used to create a round div with a background image which serves as the image spotlight. The spotlight can be overlaid on top of the main image, and positioned based on the mouse coordinates. [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CkJXJ/3/)

Although there's no natural way to soften the edges of the spotlight in CSS3 -- which would require support for adding an opacity gradient to arbitrary content -- it can be simulated using a staggered set of elements with increasing radius and decreasing opacity. [Updated demo with softened edges](http://jsfiddle.net/ga2D2/3/)

In the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ga2D2/3/), the size and softness of the the spotlight can be adjusted using the following variables:

```
var spotlightDiameter = 150;      // Base size (not including the soft edge)
var numSpotlightLayers = 6;       // More layers = softer edges
var spotlightLayerThickness = 2;  // Thinner = the softening is more subtle
```

Here's a [modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bu7rd/) where the spotlight has noticeable ripples. The thickness of the layers was increased to show more clearly how it works.

Below is a simplified version of the code for the initial version with sharp edges.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="spotlight"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    background: url(desaturated.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.spotlight {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(overly_saturated.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var spotlightDiameter = 150;

// Update the spotlight position on mousemove
$('.content').on('mousemove', function(e){
    var center = {x: e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
                  y: e.pageY - this.offsetTop};
    var x = center.x - (spotlightDiameter >> 1);
    var y = center.y - (spotlightDiameter >> 1);

    $('.spotlight').css({left: x + 'px', top: y + 'px',
                         backgroundPosition: -x + 'px ' + -y + 'px'}).show();
});

// Hide the spotlight on mouseout
$('.content').on('mouseout', function(e){
    $('.spotlight').hide();
});

// Initialize the spotlight
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.spotlight').width(spotlightDiameter + 'px')
                   .height(spotlightDiameter + 'px')
                   .css({borderRadius: (spotlightDiameter >> 1) + 'px'});
});
```

### Alternative implementations

This could also be implemented using HTML5 Canvas or SVG. Below is a browser-support comparison of the different approaches:

- `border-radius`: Not supported by [IE8 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius).
- HTML5 Canvas: Not supported by [IE8 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas).
- SVG: Not supported by [IE8 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg), or [Android 2.3 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) (which is still most of the [Android marketshare](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)).

In short, IE8 and earlier is not an option for any of these approaches, and if Android support is needed, that limits the choices to `border-radius` and HTML5 Canvas. Of course, since this is mouse-based, Android support may not be a factor anyhow.

Comment: That's great! Would it be possible to soften the edges of the circle?

Comment: @ConfusedOne: There's no natural way to do this in CSS (an image with an opacity gradient), but it can be simulated using a staggered set of elements with increasing radius and decreasing opacity. I added an updated demo with softer edges and a photo that's more suitable for this type of effect. The amount of softness is configurable.

Comment: @ConfusedOne: Thanks! Fixed a significant bug with the mouse events, and updated the demos above. It should work pretty well now in all browsers (except for IE8 and earlier, where the spotlight unavoidably appears square). Also, added a third version of the demo that better illustrates how it works (giving the spotlight a ripple effect).

Comment: @ConfusedOne: Update: [CSS Masking](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking/) provides a natural way to soften the spotlight edges in CSS3, but it's only [supported by Webkit](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask) (Chrome and Safari), and the standard hasn't been finalized yet. Using a radial gradient with varying alpha transparency as the image mask would provide some flexibility, and would even remove the need for `border-radius`. In other words, CSS masking is the truly natural way to implement this, once it's adequately supported.

Comment: @MattCoughlin That sounds great. I'll keep an eye on that one as it develops. I wonder if there is a JavaScript method to add support for that in other browsers...

Answer (score 5):

Use two SVG `<image>` elements overlaid exactly on top of one another. The bottom is the greyscale image. The top is the color image. Apply a `clipPath` to the color image, and then adjust the transform on the clipping path to reveal different areas of the upper image.

### Simple Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hZgkz/

SVG:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="250px">
  <defs>
    <image id="im" width="500" height="500"
     xlink:href="http://www.nyweamet.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/0942a__grandCentralStationExterior.jpg"/>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <path id="path" transform="translate(40,60)"
            d="M60,0 A30,30 1,0,0 60,120 30,30 1,0,0, 60,0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <use id="clippedImage" xlink:href="#im" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

and the JavaScript that moves the circle around:

```js
var tx = document.querySelector('#path').transform.baseVal.getItem(0);
setInterval(function(){
  var ms = (new Date)*1;
  tx.matrix.e = Math.sin(ms/812)*150 + 160;
  tx.matrix.f = Math.cos(ms/437)*60 + 70;
},50);
```

All you have to do is track the mouse movement and set the translation to the right spot.

Comment: That looks promising. Thank you very much. After messing around with svg and reading some articles, I was able to get this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GB5k8/

But I have a couple questions. One is can you give this a fluid width? Then two is can you make the clipPath such that its edges are not so sharp? I'd like the edges of the circle to sort of fade out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some CSS to achieve the result, if I have understood correctly your request. I've prepared a small fiddle as a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/k3AmZ/

Here's the code involved:

### HTML

```
<figure data-desaturated></figure>
<figure data-original></figure>
```

### CSS

```
figure{ width: 550px; height: 360px;
        position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
        margin: 0; padding: 0; 
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url('yourimage.png');

}

figure[data-desaturated]{
    /* I've used CSS filters tu simulate desaturation, you can use your already desaturated image */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.9);
}

figure[data-original]{
    width: 360px;
    left: 95px;
    border-radius: 180px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

figure[data-desaturated]:hover + figure[data-original],
figure[data-original]:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I've also added a `transition` to enhance the experience.

## Update

Version that follows mouse movements: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/k3AmZ/3/

Comment: How would you have the circle follow the mouse, like shining a flashlight?

Comment: Here's the updated version that follows the mouse movements: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/k3AmZ/3/

Comment: That's lovely. I made it more cross-browser compatible here: http://jsfiddle.net/xgSJ5/

Does anyone know the browser support for this solution?

Comment: The above border-radius jsfiddle answer is ideal for overlaying old photographs with new ones taken from the same location. For example, see your town 100 years ago and hover over to give a spotlight on how it looks today, or vice versa. Very nice bit of code.