# How can I create a spotlight effect that reveals part of an image on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to create a spotlight-like effect that follows the cursor in the .header section.

On mouseover, a round 220px area of the header_bg.png image would become visible.
The spotlight area would move with the cursor, but the image wouldn't - so depending on where the cursor is, you'd see a different part of the image.

I looked around but couldn't find anything that works the way I need (or close enough).
I'm not great with jquery, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Here's my HTML:

```
<section class="header" style="background-image: url("/img/header_erp.jpg");">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="large-h1 text-white">here's some text</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's my css:

```
section.header {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
}
.header:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("/img/header_bg.png");
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a circular mouseover saturation effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771396/creating-a-circular-mouseover-saturation-effect)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar post that could probably give you a good start:

[Creating a circular mouseover saturation effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771396/creating-a-circular-mouseover-saturation-effect)

by changing a little bit of CSS on his demo you can black out the image and only show where the spotlight is:

I just changed:

```
background: url(https://picsum.photos/640/480) no-repeat 0 0;
```

to:

```
background-color:black;
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zaphod42/ndb2xhfg/